# Server and client side validators - library

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, aurelia

What is best library to validate objects on server and client side ?
I'm searching something simpler - one simple config file and then in both sides something like:

var is_valid = validation(object, validationRule);

But It should have many validation options, example:

```
obj: A, B, C, D;
A = something;
B, C - Required;
D - Not needed/hidden


D = something:
C - Required;
B - optional/has value
A - Not needed/hidden
```

On client side I use Aurelia framework. It has a validation plugin, but I have no idea how to use it on server. It means that, I would like to use the same functionValidation and configValidation on server, and client;

Or perhaps - there is a plugin which would work with aurelia-validation ?

On server I use Node.js as backend;

Comment: What you're looking for is [isomorphic javascript](http://isomorphic.net/). I don't know whether or not aurelia will work on the server, though. The idea is you write your model with all the validation rules in which you then share between the client the server.

Comment: I think, I should find other library to valide my data in browser and server. Any good validators do you know ?

Answer (score 0):

I too am looking for this - it would be great it we didn't have to duplicate our work.

[Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) looks excellent for server side only validation (it powers Walmart and PayPal and is very fast) - but it's only [kinda possible](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/546) to use it on the client.

Then there's [validate.js](https://validatejs.org) which looks like it might do both.

I opened a [reddit question](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/4k76xp/how_to_do_validation_without_duplication_joi_vs/) since I can't find much info on this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement something using this commit as a reference: 
https://github.com/aurelia/validation/commit/1b701ab

I'm pretty new to aurelia so it was pretty much a copy-paste job, but it works so I guess I can be happy about that.  This is all in typescript, but you can get the general idea for a JS implementation.

```
import 'aurelia-polyfills';
import { initialize } from 'aurelia-pal-nodejs';
import { Container } from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import { configure as configureBindingLanguage } from 'aurelia-templating-binding';
import { configure as configureValidation, ValidationRules, Validator, Rule, ValidateResult, ControllerValidateResult } from 'aurelia-validation';
import { HandlerError } from 'api/handler.error';

class AureliaValidator {
  private validator: Validator

  constructor() {
    initialize();
    const container = new Container();
    configureBindingLanguage({ container });
    configureValidation({ container });

    this.validator = container.get(Validator);
  }

  validateObject(object: any, rules: Rule<any, any>[][]): Promise<ValidateResult[]> {
    return this.validator.validateObject(object, rules).then(results => {
      let isValid = results.every(r => r.valid);
      let errors = results.map(r => r.message).filter(m => !!m);

      if (!isValid) throw new Error(errors[0]);

      return results;
    });
  }
}

export const aureliaValidator = new AureliaValidator();
```

and then it's used as follows

```
import { ValidationRules } from 'aurelia-validation';
import { aureliaValidator } from "validator.ts";

let foo = {
  bar: undefined
}

let rules = ValidationRules.ensure('bar').required().rules

// This will fail
aureliaValidator.validateObject(req.body, rules)
```